# Update post meta from frontend of different page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update the post content of a specified posttype. For some reason it's not working.

I have already successfully used the code in the backend in the mail page for editing. Now I want to use it also in the frontend for employees for quick administration.

$id is transferred correctly. I used this code

This is my code snippet:

```
<?php $id = $_GET['car']; ?>

<?php
   if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
   $fields = [
       'car-highlight-2',
   ];
   foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
       if ( array_key_exists( $field, $_POST ) ) {
           update_post_meta( $id, $field, sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field] ) );
       }
   }}
   ?>
   <form method="post" action="">
     <tr>
       <td><input type="text" id="car-highlight-2" name="car-highlight-2" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($id, 'car-highlight-2', true); ?>"></td>
     </tr>
     <input type='submit' value='save' />
   </form>
```

Comment: Please, state clearly your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add name="submit" to the input.